# First element of NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have an interesting trouble:

I have a `NSArray` which is populated with some animals name (strings). And I use this array to populate `UITableView.` When you press on any `cell` (animal), you move in a detail view and you read more about this animal. Then, I improved my app and now in `UITableView` the first cell is the cell which just says how many animals in the UITableView. Its like:

Animals found: 4 (first cell)

- Dog (second cell)
- Cat (third cell and etc.)
- Hamster
- Snake

The problem is, that when you press on the first cell (Animals found: 4) you move in the detail view of a random animal. It happens because in the array at `index 0` there is an animal. Therefore, you move in the detail view of this animal. I don't want to do anything when user presses the first cell. How can I reach it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better solution is to represent in your model what you want to see in your views.  So I would do it like this:

```
myModel = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"3 animals", @"dog", @"cat", @"chicken", nil];
// here, wherever else my model is altered:
[myModel replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d animals", myModel.count-1]];
```

Now no special logic is required anywhere else except as @Praveen-K suggests when configuring cell at indexPath.row = 0...

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 4):

In your table view's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, if the supplied indexPath parameter row is zero, just return. And if it is greater than zero, subtract one from it, and that becomes the array index of the item to display. Something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tv indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];

    int idx = [indexPath row];
    if (idx == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    idx--;
    // use idx as the index into your array of animals as you did initially
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on indexPath.row condition (in your case it should be zero )

> cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

but this method will still call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, so you have to do the following

> cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: Thanks @SmartTree. based on indexPath.row you should disable the user interaction to just avoid calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath un-necessary (based your condition). so you do not even need to check in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Right, I did it. The main problem was the first element. I mean, if my array had 4 animals, the tableView will show only 3 of them, because 1 animal still existing at the first cell. But first cell doesn't show this animals, because it shows the number of animals in the tableView.

Comment: Ohh Okay that i did not see your question properly. yeah in that case danh answer is perfect. and i would have shown number of animals(which you are getting in array) may show in section title :P

Comment: hmm, maybe its better to show the number of animals in the title, I will think about it. But I am sure, its easier way, than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this......

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   if (indexPath.row ==0)
       {
        //Select first Row;
       }
    else
        {
         //Do What you Want
        }
  }
```